# Necesito reemplazar valores de una matriz (Java)

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo un laberinto y necesito reemplazar los valores (" ") con ("o") para poder crear las paredes de los niveles, pero no se como hacerlo.

El nivel estándar es el siguiente, se comienza en ("*") y se termina en ("F")

```
String[][] matriz = {
        {"|", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "|"},
        {"|", "*", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
        {"|", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "F", "|"},
        {"|", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "|"}
    };
```

Traté de hacerlo de la siguiente manera pero no me sirvió

```
for (String[] matriz1 : matriz) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            if (matriz1.equals("|")) {
                System.out.println("o");
                System.out.print(matriz1[j] + "  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (String[] matriz1 : matriz) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz1[j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Me genera un espacio sin nada y la matriz vacía.

También estoy pensando en un algoritmo de generación aleatoria, pero de momento si me pudieran ayudar con eso estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer `for` que tienes en tu pregunta en realidad es innecesario, de hecho no realiza nada ya que estas realizando una comparación incorrecta, comparando un arreglo de Strings con el caracter "|", nunca serán iguales :

```
  if (matriz1.equals("|")) {
```

Para realizar lo que deseas esta es una opción, detectando espacios y reemplazando por "o",  en cualquier otro caso agregas el valor definido en la matriz:

```
for (String[] matriz1 : matriz) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
        if(matriz1[j].equals(" ")){ //Reemplaza
          System.out.print(matriz1[j].replace(" ","o") + " ");           
        }else{
            System.out.print(matriz1[j] + " "); //Agrega valor y espacio.
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

para obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]